# SSRS 2008 Rpt Bldr 3: Go to URL action not setting parameters

Tags: url, reporting-services, parameters

I have a report which has a Go To URL link where I build a custom URL to open with selected parameters embedded. This SHOULD open the report and set the parameters so that the report runs, but it does not. Instead I get "Parameter is missing a value" error because the URL does not set the parameter values.

**Here is my URL expression in the main report:**
    ="javascript:void(window.open('"&Globals!ReportServerUrl.Replace("/ReportServer","")&"/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fRptFolder%2fsubrptMiscPHDetails&rs:Command=Render&param1="&Parameters!param1.Value.ToString()& "&param2="&Parameters!param2.Value.ToString()&"'))"

**That generates this URL which DOES open the report properly:**

```
http://<server>/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=/RptFolder/subrptMiscPHDetails&rs:Command=Render&param1=2011&param2=1
```

However, the parameters do not set set in the report itself as expected. I have checked the names of the parameters and they match exactly.

Anyone see what could be missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is I need to use the Reportserver not the manager, so this URL is the one that works:

```
http://<server>/ReportServer?/Editorial/subrptMiscPHDetails&rs:Command=Render&param1=2011&param2=1
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the reportserver URL. In my case the report opened but the parameters were not filled.