# Power BI Report Server SSRS report parameters mysteriously changing

Tags: reporting-services, power-bi-report-server

We are running Power BI Report Server Sept 2022.

I have a SSRS "Dashboard" report that uses multiple parameters to create "Go to URL" actions for various jumping points in my report.

**@PowerBIReportServer** is set to Default Value, Specify value of "/Reports/powerbi"

**@SSRSReportServer** is set to Default Value, Specify value of "/Reports/report"

Then I use these in other parameters like:

**@PowerBIHelpReport** is set to Default Value, Specify value of:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('" + Parameters!PowerBIReportServer.Value + "/General%20Reporting%20Help" + "','_blank'))"
```

Then I have a help button that has the Action\Go to URL set to **[@PowerBIHelpReport]**.
When I preview the report on my developer PC I correctly see that **@PowerBIHelpReport**:

```
javascript:void(window.open('/Reports/powerbi/General%20Reporting%20Help','_blank'))
```

But, when I deploy this to the report server the value changes to this and if I click the link I get a folder listing:

```
javascript:void(window.open('/ReportServer/General%20Reporting%20Help','_blank'))
```

I also see that the parameters **@PowerBIReportServer** and **@SSRSReportServer** both have a value of "/ReportServer"

What's going on?

I saw this question\answer:

[SSRS 2008 Rpt Bldr 3: Go to URL action not setting parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609754/ssrs-2008-rpt-bldr-3-go-to-url-action-not-setting-parameters)

But if "ReportServer" is what's needed in the URL, how do I point to the different report types: SSRS vs Power BI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So two things resulted in me getting this to work.

1. Changed `**@PowerBIReportServer**` to: =`REPLACE(Globals!ReportServerUrl, "ReportServer","Reports/PowerBI")`
2. Changed `**@SSRSReportServer**` to: =`Globals!ReportServerUrl + "?"`

This link helped me arrive at this solution for the SSRS parameter.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/Link-to-another-report-using-Built-in-Collections-global/td-p/1645567